# SAPUI5 table row delete does not work

Tags: sapui5

in SAP UI5, if a table is sorted by any column, the delete does not work. Open the below link and sort the table by Customer ID, then try to delete any row and you will notice that the wrong row gets deleted. Please help!

https://jsbin.com/qiqexo/edit?html,output

Comment: Please include the relevant code into this question.  Links break over time and we want to preserve this question to help future users.

Answer (score 3):

First of all make sure you [don't mix sap.ui.commons and sap.m](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/363cd16eba1f45babe3f661f321a7820.html) - anyway...

What you are trying is to remove a row from a table which gets its data from a JSONModel. To be safe you have to find the right "row data" in the model before you remove it. You cannot just use the selected index of the table because this index is not correlated to the index of the corresponding model data! So what you need to do is getting the data from the model that belongs to the selected row by using the table APIs. Afterwards you have to find the correct index for this "data" in the model, i.e. by looping over the model data and comparing a unique identifier (in our case the OrderID) or by using some smarter/faster algorithm... Once you got the data just remove it from the model...

Here is a working example that works even with sorting ([jsbin](https://jsbin.com/sufehiwabe/edit?html,output))

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Remove row from Table with JSONModel in SAPUI5 | nabisoft</title>
        <script src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
            id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.table,sap.m"
            data-sap-ui-bindingSyntax="complex"
            data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
            data-sap-ui-preload="sync"></script>
            <!-- use "sync" or change the code below if you have issues -->

        <script>
            var oTable, oModel;

            oTable = new sap.ui.table.Table({
                selectionMode: sap.ui.table.SelectionMode.Single,
                columns: [
                    new sap.ui.table.Column({
                      label: new sap.m.Label({text: "Order ID"}),
                      template: new sap.m.Input({value: "{OrderID}"}),
                      sortProperty : "OrderID"
                    }),
                    new sap.ui.table.Column({
                      label: new sap.m.Label({text:"Customer ID"}),
                      template: new sap.m.Input({value: "{CustomerID}"}),
                      sortProperty : "CustomerID"
                    })
                ]
            });

            oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel([
                {OrderID:10248,CustomerID:"VINET"},{OrderID:10249,CustomerID:"TOMSP"},{OrderID:10250,CustomerID:"HANAR"},
                {OrderID:10251,CustomerID:"VICTE"},{OrderID:10252,CustomerID:"SUPRD"},{OrderID:10253,CustomerID:"HANAR"},
                {OrderID:10254,CustomerID:"CHOPS"},{OrderID:10255,CustomerID:"RICSU"},{OrderID:10256,CustomerID:"WELLI"},
                {OrderID:10257,CustomerID:"HILAA"},{OrderID:10258,CustomerID:"ERNSH"},{OrderID:10259,CustomerID:"CENTC"},
                {OrderID:10260,CustomerID:"OTTIK"},{OrderID:10261,CustomerID:"QUEDE"},{OrderID:10262,CustomerID:"RATTC"},
                {OrderID:10263,CustomerID:"ERNSH"},{OrderID:10264,CustomerID:"FOLKO"},{OrderID:10265,CustomerID:"BLONP"},
                {OrderID:10266,CustomerID:"WARTH"},{OrderID:10267,CustomerID:"FRANK"},{OrderID:10268,CustomerID:"GROSR"},
                {OrderID:10269,CustomerID:"WHITC"},{OrderID:10270,CustomerID:"WARTH"},{OrderID:10271,CustomerID:"SPLIR"},
                {OrderID:10272,CustomerID:"RATTC"},{OrderID:10273,CustomerID:"QUICK"},{OrderID:10274,CustomerID:"VINET"},
                {OrderID:10275,CustomerID:"MAGAA"},{OrderID:10276,CustomerID:"TORTU"},{OrderID:10277,CustomerID:"MORGK"},
                {OrderID:10278,CustomerID:"BERGS"},{OrderID:10279,CustomerID:"LEHMS"},{OrderID:10280,CustomerID:"BERGS"},
                {OrderID:10281,CustomerID:"ROMEY"},{OrderID:10282,CustomerID:"ROMEY"},{OrderID:10283,CustomerID:"LILAS"},
                {OrderID:10284,CustomerID:"LEHMS"},{OrderID:10285,CustomerID:"QUICK"},{OrderID:10286,CustomerID:"QUICK"},
                {OrderID:10287,CustomerID:"RICAR"},{OrderID:10288,CustomerID:"REGGC"},{OrderID:10289,CustomerID:"BSBEV"},
                {OrderID:10290,CustomerID:"COMMI"},{OrderID:10291,CustomerID:"QUEDE"},{OrderID:10292,CustomerID:"TRADH"},
                {OrderID:10293,CustomerID:"TORTU"},{OrderID:10294,CustomerID:"RATTC"},{OrderID:10295,CustomerID:"VINET"},
                {OrderID:10296,CustomerID:"LILAS"}
            ]);

            oTable.setModel(oModel);
            oTable.bindRows("/");
            oTable.placeAt("tableContent");

            new sap.m.Button({
                text: 'Delete',
                press : function() {
                    var idx, oRow, oRowData, oData, oRemoved;
                    idx = oTable.getSelectedIndex();
                    if (idx !== -1) {
                        // get the selected row data from the (json) model
                        oRow = oTable.getRows()[idx];
                        oRowData = oRow.getBindingContext().getObject();

                        // now we have to loop over the JSONModel to find the right entry
                        oData = oModel.getData();
                        for (i=0; i<oData.length; i++){
                            if(oData[i].OrderID === oRowData.OrderID){
                                // we found the right entry, now remove it from the model
                                oRemoved = oData.splice(i, 1);
                                oModel.refresh();

                                sap.m.MessageToast.show(JSON.stringify(oRemoved[0]) +  'is removed');
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        sap.m.MessageToast.show('Please select a row');
                    }
                }
            }).placeAt('btnContent');

        </script>

    </head>

    <body class="sapUiBody">
        <div id="btnContent"></div>
        <div id="tableContent"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How to add a serial number column such that it sorts even when rows are deleted